# Is admonishing an asker to "use Google" as part of an answer useful?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, etiquette

([post being referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28338040))

The answer started off with a pre-amble that the information was easy to find with a web search. It seemed unnecessarily rude to me, so I suggested an edit which removed it. Three others approved my edit. The rest of the answer was untouched.

I am now being [asked by the answerer to reverse my edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28330027/coldfusion-syntax/28338040#comment45049381_28338040).

The answerer had also left a comment with the same suggestion, but it seems it has since been removed.

So what's the deal? Did I overstep? Should we leave such things in answers?

Comment: The answerer has the ability to roll back your edit himself; it doesn't require letting you know at all. Your edit was appropriate and _shouldn't_ be undone, but I don't understand why, if he's so upset about it, he doesn't just change it himself.

Comment: I don't know anything about CF, so can't comment as to whether this could have been better searched for. However if I had encountered the commentary being discussed, I would have removed it: questions need to be written for a general audience, and a telling-off is not relevant to anyone but you as the poster. It would have been fine as a comment under the question or the answer, in my view.

Answer (score 33):

If the user really felt that this was a poorly researched question that shouldn't have been asked here, then he shouldn't have answered it.

Additionally the appropriate means to provide the feedback that a question is poorly researched is to downvote the question.  Given that the question (as of the writing of this answer) has no votes on it at all, the user apparently didn't even downvote it, despite feeling that it warranted it.  He could also comment on the question to indicate what problems it has that the author should fix, in this case a lack of sufficient research.

None of this belongs in an answer though.  Answers are for answering the question, not critiquing the question.  It's entirely appropriate to remove it from the answer.

Answer (score 15):

I'll take what Servy said one step further.

As far as I'm concerned, there are two outcomes that could have come of searching for this asker's problem using a search engine:

1. They found another Stack Overflow question that answered it.
2. They *did not* find another Stack Overflow question that answered it.

In the first case, the question should have either not been asked, or at this point, should be marked as a duplicate.

In the second case, the question is fine being asked here, because it's an actual question that someone had, that's reproducible, and isn't anywhere else on the site. And just for the record, when I performed the suggested search of "coldfusion variable brackets," this was the result--a few questions on Stack Overflow, but nothing related to this.

In neither of those cases is telling the user "you shouldn't have asked this" beneficial. It was either:

1. Original, in which case it's fine.
2. A sorta-duplicate, in which case it should be closed as a duplicate to act as a sign-post.
3. An exact duplicate, in which case it should be flagged for merging.

In none of these situations is saying "try Googling it" beneficial in the answer, or even anywhere else.

You made the right call.

If the answerer feels strongly, which it seems he does, he can roll back the edit himself, which would be an unfortunate move, but no fault of your own.

Comment: SE has an expectation of research on the part of people asking questions.  it is *not* okay to be asking questions without a reasonable amount of research effort.  It is *absolutely* okay to inform someone if they aren't demonstrating sufficient research effort when asking their questions, it's just that an answer is not the appropriate place to provide that feedback.  Your implication that there is no expectation of research on the part of question askers is contrary to an enormous amount of information on this site.  As to whether or not this question is well researched, I can't comment.

Comment: @Servy True enough. I didn't mean to imply that there's no expectation of research, but rather that there are better mechanisms through which to express the expectation of research. There's a huge burden on question askers to research, and I respect and enforce that, but commenting "you should have Googled this rather than asking here" isn't constructive to that process. I would have no problem with a comment that read "I Googled '*[search terms]*' and found these resources that may help you," but unless one of them is already on Stack Overflow, I (generally) see no reason to bash the asker.

Comment: You should look at the revision history then; the user provided a specific search query and indicated that it had quality results.